# Match substring that start with prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I am stuck with a little regular expression
I am trying to match every substring that start with a given prefix using regular expression
in javascript

```
prefix = "pre-"
regex = /???/

"pre-foo-bar bar pre-bar barfoo".replace(regex, '')
// should output "bar barfoo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/\bpre-\S*\s?/g` works, assuming you want to strip out the trailing space as well (per your example).  If you want to leave it in, use `/\bpre-\S*/g`

**Correction**

`\b` only looks up word characters, and `-` is definitely not a word character.  Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support custom lookbehinds.

`/(\s|^)pre-\S*/g` should work, but there will be a leading space compared to the example output given above.  This checks for "pre-" preceded either by nothing or a space character and then followed by 0 or more non-space characters.  It removes the whole block except the space.  If the space is really important to you, you could do:

```
str.replace(/(\s|^)pre-\S*\s?/g, function(wholeString, optionalSpaceCharacter) {
    return optionalSpaceCharacter;
});
```

**Second Correction**

The complex replace I gave you won't work if you have two in a row like, "pre-a pre-b pre-c".  You'll end up with `"pre-b "` because of the `\s?` at the end.  Your best bet to get the exact desired output is to use `/(\s|^)pre-\S*/g` and check the original string if it started with "pre-" if so, just remove one space from the beginning.

```
str.replace(/(\s|^)pre-\S*/g, '').substring(str.substring(0, 4) == "pre-" ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: Try it on `f-pre-foo-bar bar pre-bar barfoo` :-) f- is the prefix now.

Comment: Of course, \b doesn't match '-' and that is the only lookbehind that is really supported.  That makes things a bit uglier.

Comment: Thks I don't really care about the extra space so that's fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var string = 'pre-foo-bar bar pre-bar barfoo';  
string.replace(/pre-[\w\S]+/ig,'');
```

Comment: This would turn `foo-pre-bar` into `foo-bar`.  The question only want to remove the prefixed words.  See the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str =  'pre-foo-bar   f-pre-foo-bar  bar pre-pre pre-bar barfoopre- pre-a pre-b pre-c';  

str = str.replace(/(^|\s+)pre-\S*(?=\s+|$)/g, '$1');

document.write('<pre>' + str + '</pre>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qTADZ/5/

We look for strings that start with a space or at the beginning of the string `(^|\s)`, that must begin with `pre-` and we take all the non space characters followed by one or more spaces  or the end of the string `\S*(?=\s+|$)`. We remove everything but the initial space/beginning of the string `$1` (that references `(^|\s)` )

Comment: This would turn `pre-foo-bar` into `foo-bar`.  The question asks to remove it completely.

Comment: We're having the exact same problems :-). `"pre-a pre-b pre-c"` will fail because of the extra spaces you're looking for at the end.

Comment: @BrianNickel Solved... But I'm not very happy because it leaves spaces at the beginning or at the end of the string.